# Divide the text by 2 characters

Tags: python, file

I have a python script which counts how many times a character is met in the text file.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import string
from collections import Counter
freqs = {}
text = sorted(open("rabi2.txt", "r" ,encoding='utf-8').read())

bad_chars = [')', '(', '-', '«', '»',',','!','—',' ','!','.','\n']
text1 = ''.join(i for i in text if not i in bad_chars) 
texts = [[words for words in sentences.lower().split()] for sentences in text1]
for line in texts:
       for char in line:
           if char in freqs:
               freqs[char] += 1
           else:
               freqs[char] = 1

print(freqs)
```

I need to divide the text by 2 characters(and by 3 characters, this is a separate program)including the space and count how many times each syllable occurred, for example:
input: hello world hello everybody
output: he,ll,o(space),wo,rl,d (space),he,ll,o(space),ev,er,yb,od,y(space) and count how many times each met,
e.g: he - 2 times
ll - 2 times
wo - 1 time and so on

Comment: Thanks and I also wish you a happy new year! Considering your question: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Could you please provide a sample input and output? Furthermore `Counter` is a great tool for things like this. You import but don't use it as far as I can see.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide by two characters"? Do you want to split the string by two different separators? Or do you want to split into "syllables" by just taking consecutive characters, i.e. split "Hello World" to "He", "ll", "o", "Wo", "rl", "d"?

Comment: please explain what do you mean saying dividing the file by two characters

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

I want to divide the text by 2 characters, for example:
input: hello world hello everybody 
output: he,ll,o(space),wo,rl,d (space),he,ll,o(space),ev,er,yb,od,y(space)

and count how many times each met, e.g:
he - 2 times
ll - 2 times
wo - 1 time and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you search for?
Note: it will not filter the special characters

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

filePath = #your file path
with open(filePath, 'r') as filePointer:
    groupList = re.findall('..', filePointer.read())

outputString = ','.join(groupList)
print(outputString)
print(Counter(groupList))
```

For your example:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

test = 'hello world hello everybody'
groupList = re.findall('..', test)

outputString = ','.join(groupList)
print(outputString)
print(Counter(groupList)) #two chars

OUTPUT:
he,ll,o ,wo,rl,d ,he,ll,o ,ev,er,yb,od
Counter({'ll': 2, 'o ': 2, 'he': 2, 'od': 1, 'wo': 1, 'yb': 1, 'd ': 1, 'rl': 1, 'ev': 1, 'er': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I want to divide the text by 2 characters, for example: input: hello world hello everybody output: he,ll,o(space),wo,rl,d (space),he,ll,o(space),ev,er,yb,od,y(space) and count how many times each met, e.g: he - 2 times ll - 2 times wo - 1 time and so on

Comment: I included the output with comma separation.